# Possible failure of the thermostat in an oven

Tags: electrical, repair, oven

I think the thermostat might have failed in my oven, just looking for confirmation that it's the most likely cause of the problem with my oven.

I was cooking a pizza in it, put the pizza in as normal once the oven temperature light went out. 8 minuets later when the pizza was due to be taken out the oven I found that the oven had completely shut itself down, even the clock display was completely blank.

The two dials (the mode and required temperature) are normally a little warm after the oven has been on but this time they felt quite hot.

After a few minuets the clock display come back on but flashing (as if it had lost power). There's been 2 or 3 times before when I found the clock display flashing, each time I just assumed that there'd been a brown-out, but thinking about it, the above has probably happened each of them times. I'm assuming that each time a safety thermal cut-out has kicked in and killed all power to the oven.

I'm going to get someone in to look at it, what would be a sensible guesstimate as to how much it'll cost to get repaired (it's in the UK)? If it's going to cost a lot to get repaired then I'll have to consider if it'll be more financially viable to just buy a new oven

Comment: We would need to know more before giving a guess of what the problem is, make and model of stove at least.  With you saying the dials got quite hot(more than normal), do think it would wise to turn off breaker for the stove, till looked at/fixed.  Asking for costs is a no no on this site since it depends on to many factors.  The person who checks the stove can give you an estimate before any repairs are done.

Comment: Put in an oven thermometer and see if the temperature appears to exceed your setpoint, or not.

Comment: @crip659 the breaker for the oven is shared with the hob, the hob and oven are actually separate. The hob is working fine. I believe that just about any new oven in the UK can be plugged into a normal plug socket.

Comment: If the stove is plugged in can just unplugged it.  Just worry about those dials getting hot, sounds like something is cooking that is not food.

Comment: @crip659 both the oven and hob are wired up to the red isolation switch (which does both at the same time), that in turn is connected to the breaker in the consumer unit